# Regex to check if JSON contains an array

Tags: arrays, regex, json

I need to be able to quickly discern whether or not a JSON data structure contains an array in it. For example the regex should return `true` for

```
{
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

and `false` for

```
{
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "[Hello World]"
}
```

Any ideas?

I Would MUCH prefer if this check could be done via regex instead of traversing json, unless anyone can show me a better way.

Comment: It would be *very* hard to do with only regex. Consider for instance a value that is a string that looks like an array.

Comment: Why? Parsing JSON is widely supported.

Comment: Why not parse the json string in a dynamic object and check if .array is null ? No need to use regex for something like this.

Comment: Ok, so you're telling me I should just go with parsing it and then traversing it to find if there is an array present? Because I need to know if there is one buried under 10 levels of objects.

Comment: Regex is generally a bad choice when one deals with hierarchical structures. Much better would be a full blown lexical parser.

Answer (score 0):

You could format the JSON on some "canonical" from using a tool like `jshon`.

**I do not recommend this approach.**

```
$ cat foo.json 
{"root": { "foo": 1, "bar": [2,3,4], "baz":"BAZ", "qux":[5,6, [7,8, [9, 10]]]}}
$ jshon < foo.json
{
 "root": {
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": [
   2,
   3,
   4
  ],
  "baz": "BAZ",
  "qux": [
   5,
   6,
   [
    7,
    8,
    [
     9,
     10
    ]
   ]
  ]
 }
}
$ jshon < foo.json | grep '^\s*\]'
  ],
    ]
   ]
  ]
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
 /:?\s+\[/g
```

And then you can simply do:

```
var json = "json here";
var containsArray = json.match(/:?\s+\[/g) !== null; // returns true or false
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pMMgb/1

Comment: Even though this works, if the json is not properly formatted, it does not function correctly.

Comment: @JanisPeisenieks, gimme an example. An array has to start with `:` with or without some space and then a `[`. Now, if it is in other formats, that isn't an array

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ph4Je/1/ As I said, technically it works. If the json is not formatted properly though...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var a = {} // required json.
var regex = /\[(.*)\]/
regex.test(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the answers, I've reconsidered, and I will go with parsing and traversing to find the answer to my question.

Regexing turned out to be unreliable, and the other options just add more convolution.

Thanks to everyone for the answers!